# изменить id в таблице на autoIncrement: true

Tags: mysql, node.js, база-данных, sequelize.js

Есть таблица, нужно в ней сделать id autoIncrement.Я использую sequelize.Пробовал

```
return queryInterface.changeColumn('Stores', 'id',{
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    })
```

но выдает ошибку -  Multiple primary key defined
убрать primary key не могу потому что к id этой таблицы уже привязаны другие таблицы.Мб я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это разовая операция? Почему ее не выполнить скриптом?

Comment: Используйте rawSQL.